# MailChimp template: Nested repeatable variants?

Tags: html-email, mailchimp

I'm building a MailChimp template and would like to have nested repeatable variants. Something like this

```
-- Variant 1A
  -- Variant 2A
  -- Variant 2B
-- Variant 1B
  -- Variant 3A
  -- Variant 3B
-- Variant 1C
  -- Variant 4A
  -- Variant 4B
```

When I nest `mc:repeatable=""` and `mc:variant=""` elements inside another repeatable/variant tag it doesn't work. The inner repeatables don't appear in the editor. Removing the inner repeatable/variant tags makes the content appear again, but the ability to repeat the content blocks is lost obviously.

Here's a full example of the code:

```
<tr mc:repeatable>
  <td>
<table>

  <tr mc:repeatable="rating" mc:variant="variant1">
    <td>    
      <div mc:edit="text">

      </div>                                                                    
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr mc:repeatable="rating" mc:variant="variant2">
    <td>                                            
      <div mc:edit="text">

      </div> 
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Has anyone been able to nest repeatable/variant blocks in a MailChimp template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest repeatable within repeatable

From MailChimp:

> The mc:repeatable attribute defines a content block that can be
>   repeatedly added to the template. When using mc:repeatable, make sure
>   to use proper nesting of items. An mc:repeatable section should never
>   be contained within an mc:edit section. Instead, nest your mc:edit
>   sections within your mc:repeatable blocks. **Never nest mc:repeatable
>   blocks within other mc:repeatable blocks**, mc:edit areas within other
>   mc:edit areas, or mc:edit images within mc:edit areas.

Comment: If you look here: http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/?_ga=1.201741201.1852877104.1415281460 you can see that mc:repeatable elements can be nested

Comment: I would be cautious with nesting them. I just checked MailChimp website again and on this page http://mailchimp.com/resources/guides/mailchimp-for-designers/html/ they say never to nest them. Maybe they need to updated docs?

Comment: It is entirely possible to nest at least 2 levels of repeated elements. However, I'm not sure why nesting variants does not work in this instance.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at **mc:repeatable** in MailChimp's Reference apparently it *is* possible to nest repeatable elements within repeatable elements, though it's "not encouraged"

http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language/

Answer (score 3):

I'm also trying to do something similar, from what I can tell, it doesn't seem possible to use a mc:variant inside a mc:repeatable and have it work the way we want.

Using the following:

```
        <div mc:repeatable="repeat-wrapper">
        <h1>Repeat wrapper</h1>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div mc:repeatable="catsdogsbirdsfish"
            mc:variant="meow meow meow!">
              <h1>Meow!</h1>
              Cats are the best!
            </div>
            <div mc:repeatable="catsdogsbirdsfish"
            mc:variant="woof woof woof!">
              <h1>Woof!</h1>
              Dogs are the best!
            </div>
            <div mc:repeatable="catsdogsbirdsfish"
            mc:variant="tweet tweet tweet!">
              <h1>Tweet!</h1>
              Birds are the best!
            </div>
            <div mc:repeatable="catsdogsbirdsfish"
            mc:variant="glub glub glub!">
              <h1>Glub?</h1>
              I don't know what sounds fish make,
              but they are the best!
            </div>
          </td>
          <td><p>End of the repeating element</p></td>
        </tr>
        </div>
```

I could create and repeat any number of Cats, Dogs, Birds or Fish. The repeating UI appeared along with the variant dropdown selector. I could also create a new *Repeat Wrapper* but I could not insert any Cats, Dogs or Birds inside the newly repeated container :/