# Mailchimp - mc:variant doesn't show in campaign builder

Tags: mailchimp

I am currently building a Mailchimp template and am having some trouble with the mc:variant attribute.

```
<div mc:repeatable="Content Section">
  <div mc:repeatable="Button" mc:variant="Content - Book now"><div mc:edit="Book now link"><a href="#"><img src="images/btn-book-now.jpg" width="108" height="44" /></a></div></div>
  <div mc:repeatable="Button" mc:variant="Content - Enquire"><div mc:edit="Enquire link"><a href="#"><img src="images/btn-enquire.jpg" width="108" height="44" /></a></div></div>
  <div mc:repeatable="Button" mc:variant="Content - Read More"><div mc:edit="Read more link"><a href="#"><img src="images/btn-read-more.jpg" width="108" height="44" /></a></div></div>
</div>
```

When using the above code in the template, it shows up in the template builder but it is hidden in the campaign builder:

Template builder:
[image: Mailchimp template builder]

Campaign builder:
[image: Mailchimp campaign builder]

Some people do argue that mc:repeatable fields shouldn't be nested but it mentions here http://templates.mailchimp.com/getting-started/template-language that it is possible but not recommended. Is there a different way I should be doing this?

Is it even possible to nest mc:variant fields within mc:repeatable fields? I haven't found any document that states an argument for or against.

**EDIT:** I removed the mc:repeatable attribute from the parent and it started working. Is there a way around this? I need the container to be repeatable so it can be used in different areas of the template.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem, mc:variant doesn't work inside of mc:repeatable parent.

It doesn't seem possible to use: 
[MailChimp template: Nested repeatable variants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937413/mailchimp-template-nested-repeatable-variants)

Comment: One solution could be variants parents.